# Como puedo hacer una animacion con el navbar

Tags: css, html5

saben que cuando van bajando por su perfil de Facebook aparece abajo como otro navbar que sale tu foto de perfil, tu nombre y despues sale lo de agregar historia...  algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues quiero hacer algo parecido a eso, he intentado hacerlo pero no se como hacer que el navbar cuando baje aparezca o cuando suba desaparezca si no que solo se queda ahi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
/* navbar */
.ul-navbar {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.9rem 0px;
  background: rgb(212, 204, 204);
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
}

.ul-navbar .icon-navbar {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

/* Navbar-2 */
.ul-navbar-2 {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3.1rem;
  height: 4rem;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!-- Iconos -->
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Navbar -->

  <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="ul-navbar">

      <li class="icon-navbar">
        <div>
          <a href="" class="a-icon"><i class="fas fa-home icon"></i></a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="icon-navbar">
        <div>
          <a href="" class="a-icon"><i class="fas fa-video icon"></i></a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="icon-navbar">
        <div>
          <a href="" class="a-icon"><i class="fas fa-users icon"></i></a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="icon-navbar">
        <div>
          <a href="" class="a-icon"><i class="fas fa-music icon"></i></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Navbar-2 -->
  <div class="navbar-2">
    <ul class="ul-navbar-2">

    </ul>

  </div>
```

Espero que me haya explicado bien ....Soy nuevo en esto y la verdad si alguien me ayuda se lo agradeceria un monton :))

Comment: Bro, tu sabes como puedo hacer esa animacion....?

Comment: Considera [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/476361/edit) para ocultar tu informacion personal de Facebook, lee e intenta sobre [encogimiento al hacer scroll](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_shrink_scroll.asp) y comentanos los errores con los que te encontraste y como haz intentado solucionar esos errores para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Oye amigo estuve una hora pensando, no sè nada de Javascript... estoy apenas comenzando a verlo y pos la verdad no se como hacer eso :((

Comment: Ya toy etresado bro :(

Comment: Alguien me puede ayudar a entender que hacer? :(